# jquery mouseleave firing prematurely in ie (8 & 9)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, mouseleave

http://standard8.tomangodns.com/

At the link above you will find a small menu icon at the top right of the site. This opens a menu when hovered. There is a mouseleave event to close the menu when your mouse leaves the menus container. This workins fine apart from in ie8 / 9 where the mouseleave event is triggered as soon as you move your cursor from the menu button.

```
//navigation slide out button
    $('body').on('mouseenter','.nav-container .nav-button',function(){ 
        $('.nav-container nav').show();
        $('.nav-container nav').animate({ width: '325px' }, 'fast');
    }); 

    $('.nav-container').mouseleave(function(){ 
        $('.nav-container nav').animate({ width: '0px' }, 'fast', function(){$('.nav-container nav').hide();});
    });
```

The jquery is a bit messy as I am trying a lot of solutions to fix the issue.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mouseout event!

```
$('.nav-container').mouseout(function(){ 
        $('.nav-container nav').animate({ width: '0px' }, 'fast', function(){
            $('.nav-container nav').hide();});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nav-container .nav-button').hover(function(){
   $('.nav-container nav').animate({width: '350px'}, 300);

},function(){
    $('.nav-container nav').animate({width: '0'}, 300);
});
```